# Is it possible to add metadata to an HKWorkout after it's already been saved?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

Can I read out an `HKworkout` and add my own metadata to it, then resave it? If so how?  Or can I only pass in metadata when I'm saving the workout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All HKObjects are immutable (the cannot be edited once saved). The recommend approach to editing an HKObject is to save a new copy with the changes you want to make and to delete the previous copy. You can only do this if your app created the original object, though.

Comment: thanks, where is the official docs that say that? Or have you just tried it and it fails